# Porque, no PHP, algumas constantes pré-definidas são case-insensitive?

Tags: php, constantes, case-insensitive

Porque, no `PHP`, algumas constantes pré-definidas são `case-insensitive` (não diferenciam letras maiúsculas de minusculas) e outras não são?

Exemplo 1:

```
echo __FILE__; // index.php

echo __file__; // index.php

echo __fiLE__; // index.php
```

Exemplo 2:

```
echo PHP_EOL; \n

echo php_eol; // Use of undefined constant php_EOL - assumed 'php_eol' 

echo php_EOL; // Use of undefined constant php_EOL - assumed 'php_EOL'
```

Como se vê, no último caso gera erro, já no primeiro não gera erro algum!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Porque é possível guardar constantes de forma case-insensitive veja na documentação [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)

> If set to TRUE, the constant will be defined case-insensitive. The default behavior is case-sensitive; i.e. CONSTANT and Constant represent different values.

Tradução: Se for definido como TRUE, a constante será definida case-insensitive. O comportamento padrão é case-sensitive; ou seja constante e CONSTANTE representam valores diferentes.

> Note:
>   Case-insensitive constants are stored as lower-case.

Tradução: constantes case-insensitive são armazenadas em caixa baixa.

Logo é possivel que:

```
__FILE__; 

__file__;

__fiLE__;
```

Tenham o mesmo valor

Comando de criação de constantes (Um deles é possivel criar constantes com a palavra `const`).

```
define ('CONSTANTE' , 12, true);
define ('CONSTANTe' , 12);
```

Comment: Simplesmente genial!!!! Eu não sabia que existia o terceiro parâmetro em `define`!. Exatamente como aconteceu com `isset`: Eu não sabia que podia ter mais de um parâmetro

Comment: Mas, agora, cá pra nós, o PHP deu uma navalhada. Pois o que vai ser das constantes definidas pela palavra-chave `const`?

Comment: Fica muito confuso somente já com o define

Comment: lança uma tradução aí pra nós :)

Comment: Seria bom colocar a sintaxe do comando também, assim não dependemos do link para entender as respostas (o tempo de vida do SO é bem maior que de qualquer outro site XD)